# How do I specify the maximum column length of a field using entity framework code first

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, system.componentmodel

Is there an attribute I can use when creating a table ? I tried `[StringLength]` but it seems to be ignored.

```
 public class EntityRegister
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     [StringLength(450)]
     public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

alternatively, you can manually do it on `Fluent API`

use `HasMaxLength(450)`

- Configuring Properties and Types with the Fluent API

  - [EF 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#1.4)
  - [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/max-length#fluent-api)

or if you want `Data Annotation`, use `MaxLength` and `MinLength` attributes

```
public class EntityRegister
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(450)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

- [Code First Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583)

Comment: I tried both of these, and dropped the database, but it re-creates with the field being (MAX)

Comment: is it the version of SQL I am using
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64) 
 Mar 29 2009 10:11:52 
 Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: the version, i think, doesn't matter at all. it's all about `EF` :D

Comment: its working like you say now, I think I must have had problems with the migration

Comment: [MaxLength] is not recognized. Do I need to include or install something extra for this? @John Woo